# Why is the unicode star ignored?

Tags: sql-server, unicode

In SQL Server, I run this simple query:

```
select iif(N'⭐' ='',1,0)
```

It returns `1`. Why?

If I try other unicode charcters, all seems ok. i.e.:

```
select iif(N'✔️' ='',1,0)
```

returns `0` as expected.

Current Collation: `Latin1_General_100_CI_AI`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some characters are ignored for comparison in certain collations. Emoticons are one such thing, where many will be seen as being equal to each other or nothing. For example `CASE N'' WHEN  N'' THEN 1 END` returns `1`.

If you *do* need to deal with such characters, you are best off `COLLATE`ing to a binary collation first, and then comparing.

```sql
SELECT 
       CASE N'' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN WHEN N'' THEN 1 END,
       CASE N'' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN WHEN N'' THEN 1 END,
       CASE N'⭐' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN WHEN N'' THEN 1 END;
```

Then returns `NULL` for all expressions.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xoyJybmR)

---

It *seems* that the question asked and the problem to solve aren't actually the same. From the comments it seems that the OP wants a `CONSTRAINT` to `CHECK` that the value isn't `''`. There are a few ways to achieve this which handle such characters.

- You could `COLLATE` in the `CHECK`:

  ```sql
  ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
  ADD CONSTRAINT Chk_YourColumn
      CHECK (YourColumn COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN <> N'');
  ```
- You could check the `LEN`, which would not allow values like `' '` either:

  ```sql
  ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
  ADD CONSTRAINT Chk_YourColumn CHECK (LEN(YourColumn) > 0);
  ```
- You could check the `DATALENGTH`, which would allow values like `' '`:

  ```sql
  ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
  ADD CONSTRAINT Chk_YourColumn CHECK (DATALENGTH(YourColumn) > 0);
  ```
- Add a computed (and likely `PERSISTED`) column to the table and put the `CONSTRAINT` against that. This will be useful if you need to compare these characters in other places, and you'll be able to `INDEX` the column too:

  ```sql
  ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
  ADD YourCollatedColumn AS YourColumn COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN PERSISTED;
  GO

  ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
  ADD CONSTRAINT Chk_YourCollatedColumn
      CHECK (YourCollatedColumn <> N'');
  ```

Comment: `iif(N'⭐' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN ='',1,0)` works too

Comment: But should it be the contrary? The star is not an emoticon, it is in "Miscellaneous Symbols And Arrows", The "check" is in "Dingbats "

Comment: I am using emoticon as a generalisation here, @GiacomoCatenazzi .

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your input. But I cannot use a binary collation in my database, as I must have the collation AI and CI. the issue occurs if i have a constraint on a field `MyField<>''`, then i cannot enter such a character. which is a problem for me.  Please advise.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you change the database collation, @YisroelM.Olewski . This sounds like a different problem to what you have actually told us. You can, however, use `COLLATE` in the definition of a `CHECK` `CONSTRAINT`.

Comment: You almost certainly don't want `PERSISTED`. It's a persistent (hah) misconception that this does anything useful for things that aren't floating-point columns. Notably, it isn't necessary to be able to index the column, and it will not (by default) cause SQL Server to use the persisted value rather than recomputing it on every access ([see also](https://sqlperformance.com/2017/05/sql-plan/p)). In this case it's doubly useless because the *only* thing collation governs for Unicode strings is the rules for comparison, and not the contents, so all you're doing is storing the same data twice.